# Matlab: signal recovery of fast transient wave

Tags: algorithm, matlab, signal-processing

I would like to recover the real waveform of a filtered signal.
A shunt is dedicated for the current sensing (fast transient). This shunt is connected to a coaxial cable (1m). This coaxial cable is connected to the input of the oscilloscope.
We can model this cable a LC filter (low pass filter), R is very low. The cutoff frequency is around 2MHz.

The signal acquired (Excel file) in the oscilloscope presents some ringing due to the LC filter response.
Indeed we have:

```
v(n)= i(n)*h(t)

i(n) is the sequence of the current wave
h(t) is the transfer function of my filter (LC)
* represents the convolution operator
```

Let’s compute the fft of each signal:

```
V(k)=I(k).H(k)
```

Then

```
I(k)=V(k)/H(k)
```

To recover i(n) I have to compute the IFFT of V(k)/H(k)
Therefore:

```
i(n)= Real ( IFFT (V(k)/H(k)))
```

Is it the right way to process to recover the unfiltered waveform?
Do I miss something?

Thanks in advance for your help!

I can share the file later.

Comment: This question doesn't seem to be about programming. Try asking on http://electronics.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on mathematics.SE  , or maybe "engineering algorithms.se"

Comment: Perhaps, I was not clear before but I am using Matlab for digital signal processing. My previous questions are related to Matlab (programming).

Comment: That's my first post and that's the last one  ;-)

Answer (score 0):

In theory is correct. In practice, you might want to obtain the real response of your cable (filter). You can use any calibration method (i.e. single tone, harmonics, etc). This might prove challenging depending on your equipment due to the high frequency response expected from the coax cable.

Another issue that you might face is that you will hit the noise floor of the system. In ideal math, you would not have such noise, but in real instrumentation, your signal is more like:

v(n) = (i(n) + Noise_i(n) * h(n)) + SystemNoise(n)

Therefore, the fourier transfroms will be biased due to the noise floor of the instrumentation. This will reflect in the inverse transforms and will not reconstruct your signal completely. The more noise you have in the system, the less accurate your reconstruction will be.